# Is it possible to run timer job on button click event?

Tags: timer-jobs, custom-timer-job

I want to know whether it is possible to run SharePoint Timer Job on button click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that but  users and application pool in a site collection do not have rights to start a timer job.You need Farm administrator permission.

```
foreach (SPJobDefinition job in site.WebApplication.JobDefinitions)
     {
                 if (job.Name == "JobName")
                  {
                      var strStatus = job.Status;



        // THE ORIGINAL VALUE OF REMOTE ADMINISTRATOR
   var remoteAdministratorAccessDenied = SPWebService.ContentService.RemoteAdministratorAccessDenied;
                              try
                            {
    // SET THE REMOTE ADMINISTATOR ACCESS DENIED FALSE
      SPWebService.ContentService.RemoteAdministratorAccessDenied = false;

                             if (remoteAdministratorAccessDenied == true)
                                            {
         SPWebService myService = SPWebService.ContentService;
          myService.RemoteAdministratorAccessDenied = false;
                        myService.Update();
                          `enter code here`
                           job.RunNow();


                                            }

                                            else
                                            {

                                                job.RunNow();

                                            }


                                        }
                                        catch (Exception ex)
                                        { }
```

http://dvsivakrishna.blogspot.com/2014/01/this-is-mainly-used-to-run-timer-job-in.html

Comment: I am facing error "Access denied".

Comment: SPWebService.ContentService.RemoteAdministratorAccessDenied = false;
While setting THE REMOTE ADMINISTATOR ACCESS DENIED FALSE

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this way even normal users will be able to start a timer job.

```
            SPSite site = new SPSite("http://site");            
            foreach (SPJobDefinition job in site.WebApplication.JobDefinitions)
            {
                if (job.DisplayName.Equals("TimerJobName"))
                {
                    job.Execute(Guid.Empty);                        
                }
            }
```

Comment: I think this will not run as timer jobs need Farm administrator account to run.Even if you say SPsecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges  it will generate error

Comment: @AmitKotha Have implemented in my project for users. It's working fine till now! Maybe because it forces execution of the code in the timer job without waiting for the timer job to run.