# How to programmatically start a TimerJob?

Tags: 2013, custom-timer-job

i have created a TimerJob which can be configured in the central administration how it should run (daily, weekly, etc).

But now i have a additional requirement that a user should be able to start the job manually out of the frontend (a site in a sitecollection).

a) is that possible? and if yes, how to achieve this?
b) how to re-design this that it fulfills the requirements?

br
Yavuz

Comment: You can find answer [here](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76125/run-sharepoint-timer-job-programatically-using-runnow-using-account-having-non)

Comment: Check my answer here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/149921/13799

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76125/run-sharepoint-timer-job-programatically-using-runnow-using-account-having-non) is same as yours.

as stated in this question you can create another timer job to set some flag status and run your actual timer job.

To run a Timer Job a user must have Farm Admin rights, so even writing the code to run in elevated privileges will not work either.